# Android BottomNavigationView App Crashes, Android Studio - Java

Tags: java, android-studio, crash, bottomnavigationview

I'm making an app with web-scraping, fragments, navigationview AND bottomnavigationview involved. It worked smoothly until I added the bottomnavigationview. When running it with usb connected, it builds all the files, but crahes after launching the main activity. I'm getting waves of error on the logcat.

I googled some of the error messages, but I couldn-'t find any answered question about them.

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.moneysaver;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new SearchFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_search);
        }


        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.nav_search:
                                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                        new SearchFragment()).commit();
                                break;

                            case R.id.nav_saved_items:
                                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                        new SavedItemsFragment()).commit();
                                break;
                        }

                        return true;

                    }
                });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

            case R.id.nav_settings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new SettingsFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_search:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new SearchFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_saved_items:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new SavedItemsFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_open:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Open Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_drawer_menu"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Here is the biggest Logcat error message**

> 2019-08-07 21:56:09.161 31782-31782/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.moneysaver, PID: 31782
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.moneysaver/com.example.moneysaver.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML
>   file line #26: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/base.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.moneysaver-2/lib/arm64,
>   /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:738)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:832)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:872)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:832)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at com.example.moneysaver.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6910)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 2019-08-07 21:56:09.161 31782-31782/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)

***build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.moneysaver"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView" on path:

^ This is the part of the error to take note of, it's most likely caused by a build problem of some kind. The first thing to try is always running a clean build and making sure the app is completely uninstalled. If that doesn't help then be sure to check that you have added the correct support library version in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    //...
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:<version here>'
    //...
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem, but I'm pretty sure I can't use compile any more. I have the android.support:design library added with implementation and I put 29.0.0 as the version. Could this be the cause? How can I get the real version of the library?

Comment: If possible show me your build.gradle, implementation is correct now my apologies.

Comment: Sure, I added it to the question's bottom, because I can't post the whole in one comment and it also displays it weirdly

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring the project solved the issue as the *android.support* libary seemed to be outdated and the whole project needed to be migrated to *androidx*.
**Refactor** --> **Migrate to Androidx**